# Clicking on TextFormField with obscureText true crashing App

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, textformfield

Flutter Application on IOS force close without any stack trace. When you click a TextFormField with obscureText value true, The app crashes immediately.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter TextFormField Error';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TextFormField'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: nameController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Email',
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: passwordController,
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Password',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the Flutter Framework. Fixed in the latest update.

```
Channel master, 1.21.0-6.0.pre.160
```